# How to force this sum to add up to a certain number?

Tags: summation, exponential-function

This is a physics application.

I have an n-length vector of

$ e_1, e_2, e_3... e_n $

These numbers are pre-set, negative, and real. (I know their values).

I am trying to set the values of another vector

$ p_1, p_2, p_3... p_n $

The p's are defined by:

$ p_i = \frac{2}{1+(exp(e_i-f)/B)} $

Subject to the constraint:

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} p_i = N $

N and B are known (N is an integer). f is what I need to figure out; basically, I need a way to tweak f so that the sum adds up to the right number. I'm not really sure how to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll need a numerical method. Start by finding two values for $f$ such that $N$ is between the sums of the $p_i$'s.

Then you can find the $f$ you want by bisection, since the sum is a continuous monotonic function of $f$.

Comment: I guess I should have included that I was wondering if there was an analytical method. I am using a numerical method currently (although yours sounds potentially faster... I was using a gradient method to minimize the difference between the actual sum and the desired sum).

I suppose an "analytical" method for this would probably involve a truncated taylor series anyway.